# Parse - Using Local Datastore with Relations

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, parse-platform

My situation includes having PFObjects that are connected with relations and I want to add to the relation using the local datastore.

So, I have a screen that creates a main object and saves it to the data store and server properly like so:

```
// Save User
PFObject *parseUser = [PFObject objectWithClassName:@"Users"];
parseUser[@"name"] = name;
parseUser[@"uuid"] = userUuid;
[parseUser saveEventually];

// Save List
PFObject *parseList = [PFObject objectWithClassName:@"Lists"];
parseList[@"name"] = newList.listName;
parseList[@"uuid"] = newList.listUuid;
[parseList saveEventually];

[parseUser pinInBackgroundWithBlock:^(BOOL succeeded, NSError *error) {
    if (succeeded) {
        // Create relation
        PFRelation *relation = [parseUser relationForKey:@"listAccess"];
        [relation addObject:parseList];
        [parseUser saveEventually];
    }
}];

[parseList pinInBackgroundWithBlock:^(BOOL succeeded, NSError *error) {
    if (succeeded) {
        // Create relation
        PFRelation *relation = [parseList relationForKey:@"sharedWith"];
        [relation addObject:parseUser];
        [parseList saveEventually];
    }
}];
```

So this part works. This took me a bit to figure out as well, but it works. Creates the User and List. Sets the relations of both then saves. Easy.

On to the **problem** area:

```
// Save List
PFObject *parseList = [PFObject objectWithClassName:@"Lists"];
parseList[@"name"] = newList.listName;
parseList[@"uuid"] = newList.listUuid;
[parseList saveEventually];

PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"Users"];
[query fromLocalDatastore];
[query whereKey:@"uuid" equalTo:[User instance].userUuid];
[[query findObjectsInBackground] continueWithBlock:^id(BFTask *task) {
    if (task.error) {
        NSLog(@"Error: %@", task.error);
        return task;
    }

    PFObject *user = [task.result objectAtIndex:0];

    // Create relation
    PFRelation *relation = [user relationForKey:@"listAccess"];
    [relation addObject:parseList];
    [user saveEventually];

    PFQuery *relationQuery = [relation query];
    [[relationQuery findObjectsInBackground] continueWithBlock:^id(BFTask *task) {

        NSLog(@"resutls: %@", task.result);

        return task;

    }];

    [parseList pinInBackgroundWithBlock:^(BOOL succeeded, NSError *error) {
        if (succeeded) {
            // Create relation
            PFRelation *relation = [parseList relationForKey:@"sharedWith"];
            [relation addObject:user];
            [parseList saveEventually];
        }
    }];

    return task;
}];
```

So what I am thinking I am doing here is grabbing the user from the local data store and adding another relation to it. But in reality, this actually is only saving the parseList to user relation. User doesn't get changed in the datastore or the server.

**Other things I've tried:**

- Querying just the server
- Pinning the User object with a name
- EDIT: includeKey (This doesn't work as the include isn't a PFObject.)

Thanks for the help in advance.

**Edit**:
Looking through the query and relation grabs I get some weird data information.

So, first off, the relation is empty when searching through it like so:

estimatedData
   0 - name - Bill Nye
   1 - listAcces - no summary
      value - PFRelation
         knownObjects - 0 objects
   2 - uuid - long string that is uuid

So this matches the server stuff, all besides the relation. But, when I query the relation and log it, I get this:
resutls: (
    " {\n    name = Okkkkk;\n    sharedWith = \" Users>\";\n    uuid = \"D8174D80-4F08-4B25-9B72-F8E00CF19DDB\";\n}"
)

So querying it, it is there, but it doesn't exist to the relation?